# Different class objects passing C++

Tags: c++, class

well i have some predefined classes

```
class x
{
   int y;
} xx;
class z
{
  int y;
} zebra;
```

and i want to pass `xx` or `zebra` depending on few conditions to a function

```
function(x xx) or function(z zebra)
```

as the functionality of `"function"` is same for both above, how can i write a single function which can take both `xx` and `zebra`. I am not allowed to redefine or declare the classes

Comment: Are you allowed to create two function *overloads*? Or a *template* function?

Comment: Use template, perhaps.

Comment: Could you create a _class hierarchy_, where both x and z are derived from a base class? Then you could write a function that accepts objects of base class but would accept also derived ones

Comment: We don't know enough about what the classes _really_ are to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something like

```
void add3(x xx)
{
    xx.y += 3;
}
```

to be usable for class `z`, you would be best off using template function:

```
template<typename T>
void add3(T value)
{
    value.y += 3;
}
```

Another option would be just to use overloading and define two functions:

```
void add3(x xx)
{
    xx.y += 3;
}

void add3(z zebra)
{
    zebra.y += 3;
}
```

Overloading may be better idea in case when the two classes `x` and `z` should differ in abstraction.

In case when their abstraction is the same, they should be based on shared interface (e.g. `base` with `y` field and both `x`, `z` should inherit `base` and then you'd only have `void add3(base b)`). You can see example of this in `std::ios` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/) where inputs and outputs (`std::istream`, `std::ostream`) are both streams, yet they provide quite different functionality when it comes to actual usage.

On the other hand, lots of STL containers do not have this interface pattern, so the template solution is not always a bad idea. It's just a matter of your style and the resources you are using.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need to do inside `function`.

If both `x` and `z` can be handled with the same code inside `function`, make `function` a template function.

Otherwise make two overloads for `function`, one taking an `x` and one taking a `z`.